# How to validate a PHP file with W3C.org

Tags: php, validation, file, w3c

I want to validate my PHP project to meet the W3C standard.  Can some one explain how to do the PHP file validation using W3C.org?

Is it possible to validate PHP files from the linux console?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not validate the PHP file on the W3C Validator. What the validator validates is the (X)HTML markup, **the output of your PHP pages**.

If your PHP project is hosted on the net, simply give the URL to the validator.

If your PHP project is hosted locally, you will have to save the output to a text file and upload this to the validator. To do this, from your browser, open the *"File"* menu and choose *"Save Page As"*... (or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>).

Alternatively, there are a variety of validator plugins available for your browser. Here are some for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=validate+html) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/search?q=validate+html).

Answer (score 3):

W3C doesn't standardize php, so you can't validate the php files themselves.  But, to validate the HTML or XHTML content of your site, just paste the url into the W3C [validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Andrew Moore is correct but I would like to add one piece of info. for others who hove come across this issue. When **hosting locally** (like when I use XAMPP) just copy all of the rendered code that is in the browser by right-clicking in the browser and choosing View Page Source (FireFox) or View Source (IE). Then highlight and copy all of the code. After that past that code into the 'Validate by Direct Input' section of the W3C validator side (http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and press 'Check'. It has worked every time for me.

Answer (score 1):

W3C validates client side markup content, like XHTML, CSS, HTML, etc. **It does not** validate server side content like PHP.

So, you can validate the output of your PHP pages, not the PHP code itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't validate PHP code on W3C validator, You only validate HTML & CSS code.
Steps for W3C validation:
(1) First take the input of that PHP code which will be in HTML. 
Or 
(1) Go to your website which you want to validate and right click on the screen and select "View Source" or press "CTRL + U".
(2) Copy that code and paste it in your editor in any txt file on your computer.
(3) Go to https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload and upload that file where your saved your code.
Or
(3) Go to https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and paste your code here.
(4) Click on "Check" button.
(5) You will see some errors & warnings of the code.
Solve it and your code will become W3C validate.

Comment: example would be great